# Looking for a Comment System based on Wicket Framework

Tags: wicket

I would like to add a comments section to our postings. Our websites are based on Java and Wicket framework. I searched for some ideas to realize a comments system but couldn't find any kind of approriate solution.

Maybe someone knows about a solution. Maybe there are other possiblities.

Tanks for answering, but this question is outdated!

Comment: What is wrong with a `ListView<String>` coupled with a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @MartijnDashorst A couple of things. For example you have to sanitise your input first (unless HTML isn't allowed at all in comments) Then you might want to add some formatting language support, e.g. Markdown. You need certain standard operations: post, preview, edit, report, delete.

Comment: May be you can use wicketstuff TinyMCE integration as a textarea, so you get the preview option.

Comment: @MartijnDashorst No, there is nothing wrong with ListView and a textarea. I can live with that and some database tables that persist the threads. That's ok. But I don't want to invite the wheel once again. I thought there was a solution OTB. Maybe I will give xaloon [link](http://www.xaloon.org/) a try. There is a comment system integrated.

Comment: I don't personally use it but there is also the [WicketStuff Facebook](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Facebook) integration which does support comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can easily write this on your own. just a view database tables for holding and managing the thread and its comments. Let the editing be done through tinymce as said an display the content as you whish. There are a view Repeaters to list a Collection of any kind holding some DAOs to iterate. For what kind of speacial features exactly are you looking for, that might be to difficult to develop them on your own? If you want to keep it simple, this would be all you need.